# Is there a way to use PrintWindow with a control? (using AutoIt)

Tags: winapi, controls, gdi+, autoit, screen-capture

I have this little piece of script but when I use PrintWindow it's only returning a black capture:

PrintWindow() is working fine with a window handle but it's not with control handles.

(Or is there a way to capture only the bottom part of the window or something in the middle without the need to capture the full window and cutting it?)

AutoIt script:

```
Local $hWnd = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:Notepad]","","Edit1")
Local $pos = ControlGetPos($hWnd,"","")
;MsgBox($MB_OK, "OK", $pos[0])
Local $Width = $pos[2]
Local $Height = $pos[3]

Local $hDC = _WinAPI_GetDC($hWnd)
Local $memDC = _WinAPI_CreateCompatibleDC($hDC)
Local $memBmp = _WinAPI_CreateCompatibleBitmap($hDC, $Width, $Height)
_WinAPI_SelectObject ($memDC, $memBmp)
;DllCall("User32.dll","int","PrintWindow","hwnd",$hWnd,"hwnd",$memDC,"int",0)
;_WinAPI_BitBlt($hDC, 0, 0, $Width, $Height, $memDC, 0,0, $SRCCOPY)
_WinAPI_BitBlt($memDC, 0, 0, $Width, $Height, $hDC, 0,0, $SRCCOPY) ;this is working now!

_GDIPlus_Startup()
Local $hBMP=_GDIPlus_BitmapCreateFromHBITMAP($memBmp)
Local $hHBITMAP=_GDIPlus_BitmapCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap($hBMP)

_WinAPI_DeleteObject($hDC)
_WinAPI_ReleaseDC($hWnd, $hDC)
_WinAPI_DeleteDC($memDC)
_WinAPI_DeleteObject ($memBmp)
_WinAPI_DeleteDC($hDC)

$sPath = @ScriptDir & '\capture.bmp'
_WinAPI_SaveHBITMAPToFile($sPath, $hHBITMAP)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have this little piece of script but when I use PrintWindow it's only returning a black capture:

First of all, I do not know the language you use, but your code and question is clear enough for me to try to offer the solution.

Right off the bat, it seems to me that your second parameter to `PrintWindow` is wrong ( it is `HWND` yet it should be `HDC` ).

Second, you have GDI leaks in your code, but I have corrected it -> see my comment in the code. Long story short, each time you `SelectObject` something into device context, you "push out" original object that "stood there" before that select. That original object must be saved and "placed back". If not, then your memory will be exhausted over time and your application will freeze. Just Google for "GDI leaks" and you will find a detailed explanation of what I have described.

Third, of course you get black capture because your initial HDC is empty -> you need to transfer the content of your `memDC` into `hDC`. To do that you need to use [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. As I have said, I don't know the language you work in but I have tried to give you pseudo code in the illustration below so you can have some clue of what to do.

```
Local $hWnd = ControlGetHandle("[CLASS:Notepad]","","Edit1")
Local $pos = ControlGetPos($hWnd,"","")
;MsgBox($MB_OK, "OK", $pos[0])
Local $Width = $pos[2]
Local $Height = $pos[3]

Local $hDC = _WinAPI_GetDC($hWnd)
Local $memDC = _WinAPI_CreateCompatibleDC($hDC)
Local $memBmp = _WinAPI_CreateCompatibleBitmap($hDC, $Width, $Height)

Local $bmpOriginal = _WinAPI_SelectObject ($memDC, $memBmp)  ;store original DC bitmap 

DllCall("User32.dll","int","PrintWindow","hwnd",$hWnd,
    "hdc",  ; I think this is an error, this parameter is of type HDC
    $memDC,"int",0)

DllCall("User32.dll","int","BitBlt", "hdc", memDC, 
    ... , ; fill in the rest of parameters
    "hdc" , hDC, 
    ... ) ; fill in the rest of parameters. Your last parameter should be SRCCOPY!

; when done with the DC, first select back the original bitmap
_WinAPI_SelectObject( $memDC, $bmpOriginal ) 
; now we can delete memory bitmap since it is no longer needed
_WinAPI_DeleteObject( $memBmp )
; delete memory DC since we performed proper cleanup
_WinAPI_DeleteDC( $memDC )
; release window's DC
_WinAPI_ReleaseDC( $hwnd, $hDC )
```

I hope this helps, leave a comment if you have further questions and I will try to help.

> (Or is there a way to capture only the bottom part of the window or something in the middle?)

Yes, but first I need to know if the above method works for you. Then leave a comment if you still need to this second part and  will try to help you.

Best regards and good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I fixed my code but I still have a black bitmap with nothing visible, my function PrintWindow works fine with windows handles, it's only not working when I add control handles.

Comment: The hdc parameter needs to be declared as hwnd I am not sure why and after the BitBlt call, my notepad edit control is filling with black.

Comment: Try to use the following examples to render `memBmp` into a file: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145119(v=vs.85).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx). Simple "Result.bmp" would suffice, just make sure that the extension is `.bmp`! This will show us if `PrintWindow` worked well since I suspect that edit control might be the problem...

Comment: @shuji: This means that the problem is in Notepad's edit control just as I have suspected. This control has its own way of painting text and simply using `BitBlt` will not help... I fear your task is much harder than you think. I will try to figure something out but don't raise your hopes too high as this is not going to be easy at all :(

Comment: I think this happens to every control since Notepad has a very standard and simple way to work. I fear that there is not a predefined function like PrintWindow that works with controls. I had this idea that controls were some kind of very simple windows.

Comment: The problem is that you are accessing edit control from your own application, not Notepad. What you are trying to do is very difficult. If you could hook into Notepad and intercept [`WM_CTRLCOLOREDIT` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you could put your drawing code in that handler and hope it will work. If I were you, I would search online for *windows hooks* tutorial.

Comment: I can't do that because the window I really want to capture detects and bans hooks. PD I am not trying to draw anything into the control, I created the hdc so I can have a snapshot of that control and OCR it to extract data. I was thinking if there was a way to use a function like PrintWindow where I could specify the coords I want to screenshot without capturing everything.

Comment: @shuji: Sadly, I am not that good with WinAPI :( I still wish you best of luck. I have upvoted your question in hope you get enough points to start a bounty... If I figure out something I will leave a comment...

Comment: You know what, I found the error in the code: the first parameter for BitBlt has to be the target $memDC which is later saved. After that the code works fine. Thank you :)

Comment: @shuji: I am so glad you succeeded! Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest - take a snapshot of the entire window and then cut out the desired portion (e.g. control) of the image. One of the reason for the black image of the control via PrintWindow is CS_PARENTDC of the control.

Comment: I don't really care if it's more difficult because in high resolution monitors takes a long time taking screenshots and cutting them. If you can think of a solution for the problem I would like to hear it, thank you.

Comment: Perhaps following demo will be useful for you (where the button "PrintWindow_M" implements my proposal): http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/printlayered.zip  (http://files.rsdn.ru/42164/printlayered.jpg).